# Parse.com - How to return 2 or more Parse Objects from Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I have 2 Parse Objects in my cloud code from 2 different query results. Is there a way to return them when `response.success()` gets called? I just need to know if it's possible or not. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Cloud Function then what you return in `response.success()` can contain anything you like.

```
response.success({
  listOfItems: someArray,
  singleItem: resultsOfOtherQuery,
  string: "Hello World!",
});
```

In your client code you have access to all 3 items. Just remember to use promises in your cloud code and all will be well.

Comment: How can I access them from my client? For example, how can I access the "singleItem" property?